# Open a dialog for a specific class with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am just trying to simplify my Jquery code. I have the next code:

```
jQuery( '.audioEnhancedHelp-opener' ).click(function() {
    jQuery( '.audioEnhancedHelp').dialog( 'open' );
});
jQuery( '.narrationHelp-opener' ).click(function() {
    jQuery( '.narrationHelp' ).dialog( 'open' );
});
jQuery( '.studentcodeHelp-opener' ).click(function() {
    jQuery( '.studentCodeHelp' ).dialog( 'open' );
});
```

and would like to use a generic label for every button with the specific class of type "*Help-opener" to open the specific dialog. Something like this:

```
jQuery( '.LABELHelp-opener' ).click(function() {
    jQuery( '.LABELHelp' ).dialog( 'open' );
});
```

My knowledge of Jquery is very poor and I can't find the answer googling. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance, 
Sergio

Answer (score 0):

I think this meets your basic requirements:

```
    jQuery('*[class *= "Help-opener"]' ).click(function() {
        var cssClass = $(this).attr("class");
        var helper = cssClass.substring(0, cssClass.length-11);
        jQuery( '.' + helper + 'Help').dialog('open');
    });
```

Note that this won't handle situations where you have multiple classes against the elements you're clicking. You may want to consider having a CSS class specific to this type of button, and then storing the dialog in another attribute (for example, 'data-dialog'); this makes the code significantly simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the selectors you can use](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors). Especially the [contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

So basicly find all elements that have the "Help-opener" as a class. Then you need to explode the class "studentcodeHelp-opener", with "-" as delimiter. Then you can fetch the "studentcodeHelp" name.

However, I'd suggest putting the target in another attribute, for example `data-target` which would ease the parsing bit. Example:

```
<div class="Help-opener studentcodeHelp-opener" data-target="studentcodeHelp"> [... ] </div>
<div class="Help-opener narrationHelp-opener" data-target="narrationHelp"> [... ] </div>
```

And then the JS for that one:

```
$(function() {
  $('div.Help-opener').click(function() {
    $('.' + $(this).attr('data-target')).dialog('open')
  }
});
```